# Gradient notation spacing

Tags: spacing, subscripts, gradient, underscore

I'd like to notate 'gradient of L with respect to a_f' which I can do with `\nabla_{\mathbf{a}_f} \mathcal{L}` and it looks like this:

[image: default]

Look at all that space between the nabla and the L! Is there a way to get the a 'under' the nabla a little more without having to shrink its size too much? How would people suggest I make this look a little better?

Comment: Why not something like `\nabla(\mathcal{L}, \mathbf{a}_f)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better if you use a more semantic command, with the advantage that you can define it to do what you precisely want.

The approach here is to add a thin negative space to the subscript, if present, but without changing the input. I use the same trick as for the standard differential, so a thin space will precede the nabla when necessary, without user intervention.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\grad}{e{_^}}{%
  \mathop{}\!% \mathop for good spacing before \nabla
  \nabla
  \IfValueT{#1}{_{\!#1}}% tuck in the subscript
  \IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}}% possible superscript
}

\begin{document}

$\grad_{\mathbf{a}}\mathcal{L}$

$\grad_{a}\mathcal{L}$

$\grad_{\mathbf{T}}^2\mathcal{L}$

$3\grad_{\mathbf{T}}^2\mathcal{L}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the picture of what you get from the previous input by just changing `\!#1` into `\mspace{-4mu}#1` (`\!` is the same as `\mspace{-3mu}`).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative space before `\mathbf{a}_f` like `\!`. If you put it after `\nabla`, you get even more negative space (normalsize), but be careful with this.

```
$ \nabla_{\mathbf{a}_f} \mathcal{L} $ 

$ \nabla_{\!\mathbf{a}_f} \mathcal{L} $
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you AboAmmar, that is helpful, this is a subset of what is suggested above.